# AttributeError: function 'ASAP1A_CCP_ComputeKeyFromSeed' not found | Python dll

Tags: python, dll, uds

I'm trying to load seedkey.dll in Python regarding UDS security.
But have an error `AttributeError: function 'ASAP1A_CCP_ComputeKeyFromSeed' not found`

```py
from ctypes import *
__dll = windll.LoadLibrary("D:\\work\\seedkey.dll")
__dll.ASAP1A_CCP_ComputeKeyFromSeed(
            c_seed_key, len(seedkey), key, MAX_KEY_SIZE, byref(key_size), level
)
```